# Using a class to keep score in python

Tags: python, class

Trying to create a simple class to keep score of a boxing match, first time implementing a class in code. Is there something fundamental I'm missing about classes?

```
class Sparring():
    def __init__(self, mywins, hiswins):
        self.mywins = mywins
        self.hiswins = hiswins

    def my_score(self, mywins):
        self.mywins = mywins =+ 1
        return self.mywins
    def his_score(self, hiswins):
        self.hiswins = hiswins =+ 1
        return self.hiswins
```

I've tried using return and not using it, all sorts of combinations, here is the function I was using to call the class:

```
def fight_match():
    print "Okay you're in the ring, ready to go three rounds with this dude"
    print "He throws a left hook, which way will you dodge?"

    dodge = raw_input()
    fight1 = Sparring(0,0)

    while fight1 != 2:
        if 'right' in dodge:
            print "Nice job, you knocked him out!"
            fight1 = Sparring(1,0)
            fight1.my_score(1)
        else:
            print 'Oh no he knocked you out'
            fight1 = Sparring(0, 1) 
            fight1.his_score(1)
```

Comment: `self.mywins = mywins =+ 1` : you are assigning self.mywins and mywins a value of 1.. is that really what you are trying to do ? ;-)

Comment: If he throws a left hook, and you dodge right, aren't you dodging into his fist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to simply increment the counters:

```
class Sparring():
    def __init__(self, mywins = 0, hiswins = 0):
        self.mywins = mywins
        self.hiswins = hiswins

    def my_score(self):
        self.mywins += 1

    def his_score(self):
        self.hiswins += 1

    @property
    def best (self):
        return max ( [self.mywins, self.hiswins] )
```

You need the function "best" for your check 'fight1 != 2', which now should red 'fight1.best != 2'. Your program could read:

```
def fight_match():
    print "Okay you're in the ring, ready to go three rounds with this dude"
    print "He throws a left hook, which way will you dodge?"

    dodge = raw_input()
    fight1 = Sparring()

    while fight1.best != 2:
        if 'right' in dodge:
            print "Nice job, you knocked him out!"
            fight1.my_score()
        else:
            print 'Oh no he knocked you out'
            fight1.his_score()
```

Another thing is, that you will probably want to move your input into the while loop:

```
    fight1 = Sparring()

    while fight1.best != 2:
        dodge = raw_input()
        if 'right' in dodge:
            print "Nice job, you knocked him out!"
            fight1.my_score()
        else:
            print 'Oh no he knocked you out'
            fight1.his_score()
```

In order to answer your comment, I will provide a sample implementatio of a whole fight:

```
import random

class Fight:
        def __init__ (self): self.scores = [0, 0]
        def heScores (self): self.scores [1] += 1
        def youScore (self): self.scores [0] += 1

        @property
        def best (self): return max (self.scores)

        @property
        def winner (self): return 'You win.' if self.scores [0] > self.scores [1] else 'He wins.'

fight = Fight ()
print ('Fight begins.')
question, answer = 'left', 'right'
while fight.best != 2:
    if random.randint (0, 1): question, answer = answer, question
    if answer in input ('He throws a {} hook, which way will you dodge? '.format (question) ):
        print ('Nice job, you knocked him out.')
        fight.youScore ()
    else:
        print ('Oh no, he knocked you out.')
        fight.heScores ()
print (fight.winner)
```

Just for completeness's sake and in order to do some code golfing, this is the one-liner which does the same:

```
_ = [print ('Fight!'), print ('You won.' if (lambda a, b: (lambda a, *b: a (a, *b) ) ( (lambda a, b, c, d, e: e if max (e) == 2 else a (a, b, c, c (b), [print ('Nice job, you knocked him out.'), (1 + e [0], 0 + e [1] )] [1] if d [1] in input ('He throws a {} hook, which way will you dodge? '.format (d [0] ) ) else [print ('Oh no, he knocked you out.'), (0 + e [0], 1 + e [1] )] [1] ) ), b, a, a (b), (0, 0) ) ) ( (lambda a: ('left', 'right') if a.randint (0, 1) else ('right', 'left') ), __import__ ('random') ) [0] == 2 else 'He won.') ]
```

Comment: @Hyperboreous This is great! However I forgot to explain that I want to make the match best out of 3. So I need a way to check if either 'mywins' or 'hiswins' have reached 2, then stop there.

Comment: The while loop will indeed stop, once either one has scored two hits.

Comment: If you want to know who is the winner, add: `def winner (self): return 'me' if self.mywins > self.hiswins else 'him'`

Comment: The loop just continues if I hit 'right' twice it just keep asking me over and over                                                            `def fight_match():
 print "Okay you're in the ring, ready to go three rounds with this dude, let's go"
 print "He throws a left hook, which way will you dodge?"
        fight1 = Sparring()
 
 while fight1.best != 2:
  dodge = raw_input()
  if 'right' in dodge:
   print "Nice job, you knocked him out!"
   fight1.my_score()
  else:
   print 'Oh no he knocked you out'
   fight1.his_score()
 winner()`

Comment: Please see the last edit of my answer. There is a sample implementation.

Comment: Does the second argument in `def my_score(self, mywins = 1):` actually do anything? It doesn't seem to. Shouldn't it be removed if it's not used?

Comment: I added it, in the case that OP some day wants to use this class for adding arbitrary scores.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Thanks yours is good, but is there anyway to get mine to work? I really wanna find out what is wrong with mine in case I encounter a similar problem in the future. I have the code here: http://ideone.com/l9fxL6

Comment: IDEone says it all: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level. You got your tabs/spaces messed up.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I figured it out, part of the problem was that we were missing the '()'after fight1.best!

Comment: Fight.best is a `@property` and hence does not need the parenthesis. That's the idea behind properties. Actually you omitted all `@property` decorators in your ideone code. Those aren't comments, they are decorators.

Comment: Oh wow my mistake, I completely overlooked them. Don't know why, thank you for the lesson @Hyperboreus

Answer (score 1):

You're reinitializing the class every time you call it. Here's a cleaner version:

```
class Sparring():
    def __init__(self, mywins, hiswins):
        self.mywins = mywins
        self.hiswins = hiswins

    def i_win(self):
        self.mywins += 1

    def he_wins(self):
        self.hiswins += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return "My wins: {}; his wins: {}".format(self.mywins,self.hiswins)

def fight_match():
    print "Okay you're in the ring, ready to go three rounds with this dude"
    print "He throws a left hook, which way will you dodge?"

    fight = Sparring(0,0)

    dodge = raw_input()
    if 'right' in dodge:
        print "Nice job, you knocked him out!"
        fight.i_win()
    else:
        print 'Oh no he knocked you out'
        fight.he_wins(1)

    print fight

fight_match()
```

In this code, `Sparring()` is a class with two functions, `he_wins()` and `i_win()`. If he wins, run `he_wins()`; if you win, run `i_win()`.

In `fight_match()`, you'll see that we create `fight`, which is a `Sparring` object—which means that it has all the methods and variables of the `Sparring` class (remember, you don't interact with a class directly—you interact with *objects* of that class). So then we accept one `raw_input()`, `dodge`. If this input is "right", then we **update the fight object to reflect one win for us** (by using `i_win()`). If not, then he wins...so we do `fight.he_wins()`, which updates the `fight` object to reflect that he won.